# How can I draw a circle that is adaptable to surrounding lines?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a `circle` using `canvas` and `JavaScript` that with have adaptable shape based on the surrounding lines. I will also make it interactive and draggable, so the shape must adjust depending on whether or not the `circle` is hitting some lines.

Here's what I have at the moment:

[image: Image 1]

And here's what I would like to achieve:

[image: Image 2]

Is this possible to achieve using the `canvas API`?

Here's my code:

```js
var canvas,
  context,
  dragging = false,
  dragStartLocation,
  snapshot;


function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
  var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

function takeSnapshot() {
  snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreSnapshot() {
  context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}

function drawLine(position) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y);
  context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
  context.stroke();
}

function drawCircle(position) {
  var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2));
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  //context.fillStyle='hsl('+ 360*Math.random() +', 129%, 95%)';
}

function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
  var coordinates = [],
    radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
    index = 0;

  for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
    coordinates.push({
      x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle),
      y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)
    });
    angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
  }

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
    context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
  }

  context.closePath();
  //context.fillStyle='hsl('+ 360*Math.random() +', 89%, 45%)';
}

function draw(position) {
  // fillBox is a local variable to the draw function
  var fillBox = document.getElementById("fillBox"),
    shape = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="shape"]:checked').value,
    //this below is what grabs the slider range and passes to the if condition for the shape polygon
    polygonSides = document.getElementById("polygonSides").value,
    polygonAngle = document.getElementById('polygonAngle').value,
    linecaps = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="linecaps"]:checked').value,
    globalComposite = document.querySelector('option[type="radio"][name="globalComposite"]:checked').value;

  context.globalCompositeOperation = globalComposite;
  context.lineCap = linecaps;
  if (shape === "circle") {
    drawCircle(position);
  }
  if (shape === "line") {
    drawLine(position);
  }

  if (shape === "polygon") {
    drawPolygon(position, polygonSides, polygonAngle * (Math.PI / 180));
  }
  if (shape !== 'line') {
    if (fillBox.checked) {
      context.fill();
    } else {
      context.stroke();
    }
  }
}

function dragStart(event) {
  dragging = true;
  dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
  takeSnapshot();
}

function drag(event) {
  var position;
  if (dragging === true) {
    restoreSnapshot();
    position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    draw(position, "polygon");
  }
}

function dragStop(event) {
  dragging = false;
  restoreSnapshot();
  var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
  draw(position, "polygon");
}

function changeWidth(event) {
  context.lineWidth = this.value;
  event.stopPropogation();

}

function changeColor(event) {
  context.fillStyle = this.value;

  event.stopPropogation();
}

function changeStrokeColor(event) {
  context.strokeStyle = this.value;

  event.stopPropogation();
}

function changeCanvasColor(event) {
  context.save();
  context.fillStyle = document.querySelector('#canvasColor').value;
  //context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over'; // this is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation

  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.restore();
}

function myFunction() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}



function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("cv0");
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var strokeColor = document.getElementById('strokeColor');
  context.strokeStyle = strokeColor.value;
  var fillColor = document.getElementById('fillColor');
  context.fillStyle = fillColor.value;
  var lineWidth = document.getElementById('lineWidth');
  context.lineWidth = lineWidth.value; //the .value has be here as well as the above variable for this is where it is controlled from. Not each individual global function.
  //context.lineCap = 'round';
  var canvasColor = document.getElementById('canvasColor');

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
  lineWidth.addEventListener('input', changeWidth, false);
  fillColor.addEventListener('input', changeColor, false);
  strokeColor.addEventListener('input', changeStrokeColor, false);
  canvasColor.addEventListener('input', changeCanvasColor, false);
  clearCanvas.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

```css
#cv0 {
  border: solid gray;
}

#controls {
  margin-top: -14.45rem;
  margin-left: 25rem;
  font-family: Brooklyn, 'sans-sherif';
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

#controls2 {
  margin-top: -15.45rem;
  margin-left: 40rem;
  font-family: Brooklyn, 'sans-sherif';
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

#controls3 {
  margin-top: 0.01rem;
  margin-left: 0rem;
  background: hsl(42, 63%, 99%);
  color: black;
  font-family: Brooklyn, 'sans-sherif';
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='cv0' width=400 height=300></canvas>

<div id="controls">
  <p><label>Fill: <input id="fillBox" type="checkbox" checked="checked"></label></p>

  <div class="lightBorder">
    <p><input type="radio" name="shape" value="line" checked="checked">Line</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="shape" value="circle">Circle</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="shape" value="polygon">Polygon</p>
  </div>

  <p><label>Line With: <input id="lineWidth" type="range" step="1" min="3" max="20"></label></p>

  <p><label>Polygon Sides: <input id="polygonSides" type="range" step="1" min="3" max="10"></label></p>

  <p><label>Polygon Angle: <input id="polygonAngle" type="range" step="22.5" min="0" max="90"></label></p>

  <p><label>Fill Color: <input id="fillColor" type="color" value='#c84341'></label></p>
  <p><label>Stroke Color: <input id="strokeColor" type="color" value='#624c6c'></label></p>
</div>

<div id='controls2'>
  <p> LineCap Style: </p>
  <p><input type='radio' value='round' name='linecaps' id='roundshape' checked="checked">Round</p>
  <p><input type='radio' value='square' name='linecaps' id='sqhape'>Square</p>
  <p><input type='radio' value='butt' name='linecaps' id='buttshape'>Bevel</p>
  <label>Global Composite Control:</label>

  <select id='controls3'>
    <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='source-over' checked='checked'>source-over
      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='source-in'>source-in</option>

      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='source-out'>source-out</option>
      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='destination-out'>destination-out</option>

      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='destination-in'>destination-in</option>
      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='destination-over'>destination-over</option>

      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='source-atop'>source-atop</option>
      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='destination-atop'>destination-atop</option>

      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='xor'>xor</option>
      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='lighter'>lighter</option>
      <option type='radio' name='globalComposite' value='color-burn'>color-burn</option>
  </select>

  <p><label>Canvas Color: <input id="canvasColor" type="color" value='#f7f5ec'></label>
  </p>

  <button id='clearCanvas' onclick='myFunction()'>Clear Canvas</button>
```

Comment: You need to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip to set up a clipping region.  That's not necessarily going to be easy.  How would you decide to clip to the south and west of those lines, and not the other sides?

Comment: Interesting suggestion @TimRoberts! I was playing with a clipping example, but you're right, I can't find an answer to the question you posed. My code example: https://jsfiddle.net/hncqbhah/2/

Might be time for me to explore SVGs instead of canvas, I suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what you show in the image is possible with the canvas API.

You can see it in this example...

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("cv0");
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.lineWidth = 8
context.lineCap = 'round'

context.beginPath()
context.fillStyle = "red"
context.moveTo(10, 80)
context.arc(30, 70, 40, 0.25, -2.1, true)
context.fill()

context.beginPath()
context.fillStyle = "black"
context.moveTo(10, 10)
context.lineTo(10, 80)
context.lineTo(80, 80)
context.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id='cv0' width=200 height=100></canvas>
```

But you will need to do those calculation for the arc